# "[object Object]" is not a valid number jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Below is my html code for 4 inputs. I am using jquery ui slider to represent these percentage fields.

```
               <div class="turnover">
                      <label for = "{{  form.turnover.id_for_label  }}">Umsatz des verkauften Artikels am Gesamtumsatz</label>

                      {{ form.turnover }}

                      <div id="turnover_slider"></div>

                      {{ form.turnover.errors }}
                </div>

              <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="sold_qty">  
                      <label for = "{{  form.sold_qty.id_for_label  }}">Zahl der verkauften Menge des Artikels zur gesamten Absatzmenge</label>

                        {{ form.sold_qty }}

                      <div id="sold_qty_slider"></div>

                      {{ form.sold_qty.errors }}
                </div>

              <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="produced_qty">
                      <label for = "{{  form.produced_qty.id_for_label  }}">Zahl der produzierten Menge des Artikels relativ zur gesamten Produktmenge</label>

                        {{ form.produced_qty }}

                      <div class="produced_qty_slider"></div>         

                        {{ form.produced_qty.errors }}
                </div>

              <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="var_pay">
                        <label for = "{{  form.var_pay.id_for_label  }}">Prozent der variablen Verg&uuml;tung an der Gesamtverg&uuml;tung</label>

                        {{ form.var_pay }}

                        <div class="var_pay_slider"></div>
                        {{ form.var_pay.errors }}
                    </div>

              <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="contracts">
                        <label for = "{{  form.contracts.id_for_label  }}">Anzahl der abgeschlossenen Vertr&auml;ge im Veranlagungszeitraum</label>
                        {{ form.contracts }}
                        {{ form.contracts.errors }}
                </div>
```

Jquery code is

```
$( "#turnover_slider" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 100,

      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id_turnover" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
$( "#id_turnover" ).val( $( "#turnover_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );




$( "#sold_qty_slider" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id_sold_qty" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
$( "#id_sold_qty" ).val( $( "#sold_qty_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );



$( "#var_pay_slider" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id_var_pay" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
$( "#id_var_pay" ).val( $( "#var_pay_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

The slider works fine for the first 2 input fields (ie) for turnover and sold_qty fields. But it does not work for the produced_qty and var_pay. It throws the error '"[object Object]" is not a valid number'. Need your experts help.

Comment: check for existance of `produced_qty`

Comment: sounds like `{{ form.var_pay }}` and `{{ form.produced_qty }}` arent numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first two case you have correct `id` to DOM element as :

```
<div id="turnover_slider"></div>
<div id="sold_qty_slider"></div>
```

but for rest of the two you have `class` assigned and not the `id`. Please correct it:

```
<div class="produced_qty_slider"></div>
<div class="var_pay_slider"></div>
```

Or change the JS code to change the jQuery selector for them as :

```
$( ".produced_qty_slider" ).slider({

$( ".var_pay_slider" ).slider({
```